# how to tell if user responded to my facebook request?

Tags: facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-invite

I don't really understand what i should do after invitable friends call. So this is the procedure till im stuck:

I have a facebook canvas app, but the app itself is mostly ios/android native so the canvas is for redirection only.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.0
```

according to this:

*. i get the list of friends when i do the call (i did it)

*. i get the tokens, when i press a friend, a token is entering the array which is later used for "to" in the javascript api

*. i press send and do the invite.

Ok now i see this:

```
Rewarding the Sender

1)Upon sending the request, store the request id returned in the response from the Game Request Dialog and match it upon receipt to reward the sender.

2)Read all the requests for the receiver and reward the sender based on the ID in the "from" field.
```

What is the exact way to do those two  ( 'and match it upon receipt to reward the sender'  <- and what the hell does that mean? )?

Comment: Stacked with the same problem) please write here the way of doing this, if you will get any solution!